# Which site does this question about networking belong to?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have a question, and I have no idea where it belongs to.

To cut it short - the question is about networking (specifics about the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol), but the problem is that I have no idea where it belongs too. When I was previously posting similar questions on Stack Overflow, people were not really happy regarding them. Super User and Server Fault does not look applicable, and there is no such site as Networking.

What is the right solution?

Here is a question:

> In the [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) protocol, the client is submitting his MAC-address to a DHCP server in order to get an IP address. On the opposite, in the ARP protocol, the client is telling the IP address of the device and is asking who knows the device's [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). Why exactly do I need to know the MAC address of the device?

Comment: If you care to go into more detail about your question, we can probably give you a better answer. What do you need to know about ARP... And why do you need to know it?

Comment: hhmm..! Looks like possible proposal to Area 51..?

Comment: You could ask that on Super User.

Comment: @CRoshanLG: No, there is sufficient fragmentation of the IT sector here already thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask this question on either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). If the community you ask doesn't think it's on topic for them you'll quickly find out.